# git push origin master not working

Tags: github

I created a new repository on github, and linked it with my local repository using - git remote add origin (gihub-Link).

But when I am using git push origin master it is showing this-----

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you the remote site contains data that your local repo doesn't you'd either have to merge that with your local data or do a force push. A force push will overwrite anything that's on the remote.